Problem with expo react naitive responsive desing
I finished my app at expo but when I downloaded the app on real devices, the responsive design works poorly, but in the emulator it works perfectly. Does anyone know why this could be? I tried the app on different emulated devices and it worked fine on all of them, and for some reason, in my xiaomi works fine, but in a samsung of a very similar size works very bad


i try use "react-native-responsive-screens" library like this , but nothing works
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    selectLiftingContainer : {
        flexDirection : "row",
        gap :  (Dimensions.get("window").width < 400 ? 5 : wp('2%')) ,
        margin : 35,
        marginTop : (Dimensions.get("window").width < 400 ? 20 : 45)
    },
    selectLiftButton : {
        backgroundColor : "#FBFBFB",
        padding : 9,
        borderRadius : 30,
        width : wp('28%')
    },
    buttonText : {
        textAlign : "center",
        fontSize : hp('2%')

